# detect vrapper in .vimrc

Tags: vim, eclipse-plugin

In my .vimrc I have the following:

```
" Use j/k to navigate the word completion popup menu
inoremap <expr> j pumvisible() ? "\<C-N>" : "j"
inoremap <expr> k pumvisible() ? "\<C-P>" : "k"
```

This works perfect when using vim within a terminal, however this is not compatible with vrapper (eclipse vim plugin). Vrapper completely stops working when these settings are in my .vimrc. In my home directory I have a `.vrapperrc` file, which is simply a symobolic link pointing to my `.vimrc` file. Hence the vim settings which are loaded for vim / vrapper are equal.

Is there a way that in my .vimrc I can detect that the settings are loaded for vrapper instead of default (terminal) vim. That way I would like to disable these settings for vrapper and just load them when vim is used from the command line. Perhaps there is a different smart way to solve this issue. Of course I could create two .vimrc files, one for default vim and one for vrapper, however that way I would need to maintain two files which I would like to prevent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem in which Vrapper executed the contents of my functions immediately because it didn't understand what they were.

I solved it by wrapping the vim only code with

```
if has("eval")
    " vim only code
endif
```

which caused Vrapper to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

As [@romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) noted, Vrapper only understands a limited set of Vim commands and features. Function definitions, ternaries and `<expr>` are definately not supported.

---

If you are willing to split your rc files, you could use the `source` command to at least reuse one of them.

For example, put these basic settings in your `.vrapperrc`:

```
set ignorecase
set hlsearch
```

Then you can do this in your `.vimrc`:

```
" Load common settings for Vim / Vrapper
source .vrapperrc
" ... Other Vim-specific settings
```

Note that Vrapper also has a `source` command, so you could in theory have 3 rc files with the "common" settings shared between the two:

Example `.vrapperrc`:

```
set novisualmouse
source .vimcommonrc
```

Example `.vimrc`

```
" Use j/k to naviage the word completion popup menu
inoremap <expr> j pumvisible() ? "\<C-N>" : "j"
inoremap <expr> k pumvisible() ? "\<C-P>" : "k"
source .vimcommonrc
```

And the common settings:

```
set hlsearch
set ignorecase
```

It's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can *detect Vrapper*, but you can instead write a command that real Vim will process and Vrapper will ignore.

Example: mapping `<KMinus>`:

```
nnoremap <KMinus> q
```

If Vrapper runs that, it crashes. Let's make it ignore it. There are many ways:

```
if v:true
  nnoremap <KMinus> q
endif
```

```
if v:true | nnoremap <KMinus> q | endif
```

```
exec 'nnoremap <KMinus> q'
```

There's also this more "aggressive" version, if the other ones don't work. It's useful for multiple commands:

```
if v:true |
  \nmap <C-Bslash> gcc |
  \vmap <C-Bslash> gc |
  \imap <C-Bslash> <C-o><C-Bslash> |
\endif
```

You can even add a `finish` statement which Vim will treat as "I should stop reading this file" and Vrapper will probably ignore and keep executing the file, making it ideal to precede Vrapper-only commands:

```
if v:true
  " Vim-only stuff

  finish
endif

" Vrapper-only stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

How do you think it would work?

Your `~/.vimrc` is not a sentient being that can take decisions by itself: it needs to be sourced by a program that understands it and… that program is Vim.

Vrapper only supports [a subset of Vim's vocabulary](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/documentation/?topic=configuration) so it is not very reasonable to expect it to behave *exactly* like Vim. The main missing feature that would make possible the detection you are asking about is vimscript: since Vrapper doesn't support it you can't use an `if-else-endif` construction!

Because the two programs support vastly different sets of options and commands I'm afraid you will have to manage two separate files.

Did you try Vrapper's `:source` command?